# How to replace two Java Constructors with one generic Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have the following two java methods(simplified). I would like to replace these two methods with one method. The reason for wanting to do this is one method is used for local testing, and one method is using during run on a Hadoop cluster. I just spent a while debugging my code before realising I had adjusted one method and not the other, and would like to know how to avoid this silly mistake in the future.

```
public MyObject(ArrayList<String> values){
    for(String val: values){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
}

public MyObject(Iterable<Text> values){
    for(Text val: values){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
}
```

Text is an apache hadoop class. Here is a link to source code.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.java

Comment: Does String extends Text? And can you call one from the other?

Comment: public MyObject (Collection values) { } should do that since Iterable and ArrayList are (not 100% sure) extended from Collection

Comment: Iterable is not extended from Collection - it's the other way around.

Comment: Why are you creating these `MyObject` instances if all that is happening in them is to dump the `toString()` of the elements of an `Iterable`?  What are the instances for?  What state - in your real code - do they have?  A proper answer to your question probably depends on know more about what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Really a lot goes into the constructor after the for-each loop. I am not actually printing each string but adding them to a complicated map. I have stripped down the code to just the bare essentials relevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not using anything specific to `String` or `Text` (whatever that is) in your constructors, you could take `Iterable<? extends Object>` as the parameter:

```
public MyObject(Iterable<? extends Object> values){
    for(Object val: values){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I add this in, it gives me an error for my second method because this obviously replaces that. But my ArrayList method is not throwing an error which leads me to believe this won't accomplish the goal.. but I think we are closer using ? extends Object over Text or String. 

Is there a "object" keyword equivalent for Iterable/ArrayList?

Comment: @djc391 `ArrayList<T>` implements `Iterable<T>` through a chain of inheritance `ArrayList<T>` <-- `Collection<T>` <-- `Iterable<T>`, so this should be able to replace both constructors.

Comment: What is the difference between have <? extends Object> compared to doing public class MyObject<T>{ public My Object<T> values){...}}

Comment: @djc391 I have shared you a link in my post. Just read it for more understanding on Generic. Look at [More Fun with Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

Comment: @djc391 The `MyObject<T>` approach makes *your* class generic; the `<? extends Object>` leaves your class non-generic.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
public MyObject(Iterable<? extends Object> values){
    for(String val: values){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
}
```

And lose the first constructor entirely.

Alternatively look at whether you can have one constructor modify the parameters and then call the other.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Very true, I've changed it to Object since that will work in all cases here and upvoted your answer :)

Comment: The `? extends Object` can be shortened to `?`.  However I expect this doesn't address the real issue.  After all, if all that was required was a method dump the `toString()` of the elements of an `Iterable` why is there a `MyObject` involved at all?  A proper answer to this question probably depends on what else is happening in the (real) ctors.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **[Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/)**.

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) also implements  [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) so any thing that implements `Iterable` can pass in the constructor.

There is no need for any other constructor. This single constructor can serve the purpose of all type of `Iterable` classes.

```
public class MyObject<T> {

    public MyObject(Iterable<T> values) {
        for (T val : values) {
            System.out.println(val.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the added value of playing <T> after public class MyObject?

Comment: In this case `T` can be any type of `Object`. You can make if more generic something like `T extends XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

Is `Text` a class in your own code base?  If so, could you make it implement `CharSequence` which `java.util.String` already does (in later versions of Java - not sure since when).  Then your one ctor would be:

```
public MyObject(Iterable<? extends CharSequence> values) { ... }
```

(I am assuming your real code is doing more in the ctor than just printing the objects; otherwise why would you be creating an `MyObject` instance in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

You could just try...

```
public MyObject(Collection collection) {

   for (Object obj : collection) {
      System.out.println(obj.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Causing errors with the Iterable function. It was explained elsewhere in this question that ArrayList<T> <-- Collection<T> <-- Iterable<T> .